# Collection of subsets with more than $n\choose n/2$ elements must have set contained in another

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, set-partition

I have a set $A$ of size $n$.
I have a collection of subsets of $A$ that contains $k>{n\choose n/2} $ elements.
I want to prove that there are two sets $B, C$ in this collection such that $B\subset C$.
Any idea ?

Comment: This result is called Sperner's theorem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperner%27s_theorem

Comment: The proof on wikipedia uses the stronger statement: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lubell%E2%80%93Yamamoto%E2%80%93Meshalkin_inequality

Comment: Thank you very much